# What is the standard formula at oral exams?

Tags: questions

In my language/country when a teacher is testing a student (in ordinary classroom routine or at an exam) will say"

- (would you like to) Talk about Milton!
- Tell me what you know about Coleridge/ the French Revolution/ etc

I realize that this translation doesn't sound well in English, so, could you tell me what is the common way to interrogate a student?

Comment: The second prompt sounds fine. But are you testing content knowledge or language proficiency (grammar, intonation, vocabulary, etc.), or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I've been given oral exams, usually the questions were more specific. An example might be "*Describe the series of events that lead up to the French Revolution*."

In your first example, the grammar isn't quite what we'd use in English. Rather than "*Would you like to talk about Milton?*" it would be more common to just say, "*Tell me about Milton.*" Or as a question, one could ask "*Who was John Milton?*", or a more specific question: *"What effect did Milton's poetry have on English culture?"*

Overall, though, the basic examples you gave are reasonable examples of how an oral exam would be conducted. My examples are only basic changes to how the questions would be structured.